# 412 (Precondition Failed) when trying to POST PDF file to S3 pre-signed URL

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-post, serverless

This is Part Two of my journey to try and upload a file from the browser to an S3 bucket. Check out [Part One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56709408/403-forbidden-when-trying-to-upload-pdf-as-blob-to-s3-bucket-using-put/56715719#56715719).

### What I'm Trying to Do

Upload a file (PDF) from my browser client (Vue/Nuxt app) to an S3 bucket.

### What I'm Using

## Front End

Nuxt, Vue, Axios, Fetch.

## Back End

JS, Serverless Framework for easy AWS deployment.

### Permissions

The permissions are good, unless there is some permission regarding POSTing to an S3 bucket that I don't know about. The S3 bucket is setup to allow CORS; all methods, all origins. **No, the Lambda shown here does not have the incorrect permissions**; if it did, I would not be able to get a pre-signed URL successfully.

### How It Should Work

Based on [this](https://medium.com/@aidan.hallett/securing-aws-s3-uploads-using-presigned-urls-aa821c13ae8d) and [this](https://github.com/jbesw/askjames-s3uploader), I thought I'd be able to PUT (or POST) a PDF to an S3 bucket by first retrieving a pre-signed URL from the my backend code shown below, which called `s3.getSignedUrl('putObject')`. I was able to easily get this URL to the frontend, but PUTing (or POSTing) the PDF to the returned URL wasn't working.

What I did in Part One proved useless, and I haven't been able to track down an answer as to why, so I decided to try another JS AWS SDK function called `createPresignedPost`.

Instead of a 403 error, I get a 412 error. After reading, it seemed like I wasn't passing the right options into the POST request. After looking at this, I set up my request as shown below, but still got the error.

### Code

### Backend (fileReceiver.js):

```
const getUploadUrl = async () => {
  const fileId = uuidv4();

  let params = {
    Bucket: 'the-chumiest-bucket',
    ContentType: 'application/pdf',
    Conditions: [
      {'bucket': 'the-chumiest-bucket'}, // added to both places 
      ['starts-with', '$key', 'path/to/where/the/file/should/go/'],
      {'acl': 'public-read'},
      {'success_action_status': '200'},
      ['content-length-range', 1, 1024 * 1024 * 15],
      ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'application/pdf'],
    ]
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.createPresignedPost(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Presigning post data encountered an error', err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        //data.Fields.key = 'path/to/uploads/${filename}';
        console.log('The post data is', data);
        resolve({
          'statusCode': 200,
          'headers': { 
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
          },
          'body': JSON.stringify({
            'data': data,
          }),
        });
      }
    });
  });

};
```

### Frontend (fileUploader.js):

I wanted to structure my request to match [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html).

```
uploadFile: async function(e) {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: API_GATEWAY_URL,
        data: {
          'fileName': this.fileNames[0],
          'contentType': this.file.type || 'application/pdf',
          'fileLength': this.file.length,
        },
        body: {
          'fileName': this.fileNames[0],
          'contentType': this.file.type || 'application/pdf',
          'fileLength': this.file.length,
        },
      });

      console.log('upload file response:', response);

      let binary = atob(this.file.split(',')[1]);
      let array = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }

      let fields = response.data.data.fields;
      let blobData = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'application/pdf'});

      if (blobData.type != 'application/pdf') {
        console.error('Filetype is wrong! Upload a PFD or youre dead to me');
      }

      console.log(`Uploading "${this.fileNames[0]}" to bucket "${response.data.data.fields.bucket}"`);

      const postHeaders = {
        'Policy': fields.Policy,
        'X-Amz-Algorithm': fields['X-Amz-Algorithm'],
        'X-Amz-Credential': fields['X-Amz-Credential'],
        'X-Amz-Security-Token': fields['X-Amz-Security-Token'],
        'X-Amz-Signature': fields['X-Amz-Signature'],
        'Content-Type': blobData.type || 'application/pdf',
        'acl': 'public-read',
        'key': 'path/to/where/the/file/should/go/' + this.fileNames[0],
      }

      const result = await fetch(response.data.data.url, {
        method: 'post',
        body: blobData,
        headers: postHeaders,
      });

      this.uploadUrl = response.data.uploadURL.split('?')[0];
    },
```

### Serverless Config (serverless.yml):

```
service: ocr-space-service

provider:
  name: aws
  region: ca-central-1
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  timeout: 20

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-existing-s3
  - serverless-step-functions
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-plugin-include-dependencies

layers:
  spaceOcrLayer:
    package:
      artifact: spaceOcrLayer.zip
    allowedAccounts:
      - "*"

functions:
  fileReceiver:
    handler: src/node/fileReceiver.handler
    role:
    events:
      - http:
          path: /doc-parser/get-url
          method: get
          cors: true
  startStateMachine:
    handler: src/start_state_machine.lambda_handler
    role: 
    runtime: python3.7
    layers:
      - {Ref: SpaceOcrLayerLambdaLayer}
    events:
      - existingS3:
          bucket: ingenio-documents
          events:
            - s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: 
            - suffix: .pdf
  startOcrSpaceProcess:
    handler: src/start_ocr_space.lambda_handler
    role: 
    runtime: python3.7
    layers:
      - {Ref: SpaceOcrLayerLambdaLayer}
  parseOcrSpaceOutput:
    handler: src/parse_ocr_space_output.lambda_handler
    role: 
    runtime: python3.7
    layers:
      - {Ref: SpaceOcrLayerLambdaLayer}
  renamePdf:
    handler: src/rename_pdf.lambda_handler
    role: 
    runtime: python3.7
    layers:
      - {Ref: SpaceOcrLayerLambdaLayer}
  parseCorpSearchOutput:
    handler: src/node/pdfParser.handler
    role: 
    runtime: nodejs10.x
  saveFileToProcessed:
    handler: src/node/saveFileToProcessed.handler
    role: 
    runtime: nodejs10.x

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    ocrSpaceStepFunc:
      name: ocrSpaceStepFunc
      definition:
        StartAt: StartOcrSpaceProcess
        States:
          StartOcrSpaceProcess:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-startOcrSpaceProcess"
            Next: IsDocCorpSearchChoice
            Catch:
            - ErrorEquals: ["HandledError"]
              Next: HandledErrorFallback
          IsDocCorpSearchChoice:
            Type: Choice
            Choices:
              - Variable: $.docIsCorpSearch
                NumericEquals: 1
                Next: ParseCorpSearchOutput
              - Variable: $.docIsCorpSearch
                NumericEquals: 0
                Next: ParseOcrSpaceOutput
          ParseCorpSearchOutput:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-parseCorpSearchOutput"
            Next: SaveFileToProcessed
            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: ["SqsMessageError"]
                Next: CorpSearchSqsErrorFallback
              - ErrorEquals: ["DownloadFileError"]
                Next: CorpSearchDownloadFileErrorFallback
              - ErrorEquals: ["HandledError"]
                Next: HandledNodeErrorFallback
          SaveFileToProcessed:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-saveFileToProcessed"
            End: true
          ParseOcrSpaceOutput:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-parseOcrSpaceOutput"
            Next: RenamePdf
            Catch:
            - ErrorEquals: ["HandledError"]
              Next: HandledErrorFallback
          RenamePdf:
            Type: Task
            Resource: "arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:#{AWS::StackName}-renamePdf"
            End: true
            Catch:
              - ErrorEquals: ["HandledError"]
                Next: HandledErrorFallback
              - ErrorEquals: ["AccessDeniedException"]
                Next: AccessDeniedFallback
          AccessDeniedFallback:
            Type: Fail
            Cause: "Access was denied for copying an S3 object"
          HandledErrorFallback:
            Type: Fail
            Cause: "HandledError occurred"
          CorpSearchSqsErrorFallback:
            Type: Fail
            Cause: "SQS Message send action resulted in error"
          CorpSearchDownloadFileErrorFallback:
            Type: Fail
            Cause: "Downloading file from S3 resulted in error"
          HandledNodeErrorFallback:
            Type: Fail
            Cause: "HandledError occurred"
```

### POST Response

> POST https://s3.{regionName}.amazonaws.com/{bucketName} 412 (Precondition Failed)
>   `PreconditionFailed`At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not holdBucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data934186E69EF6F90EAPU1d8pkKL3XxXjZ8T1oXkWuDRECAPZROklZbHBv+lmNRv/ivoLO/8BhoS8QYXA98850RhrGwhI=

### Edit

Looks like the request is being 412'd because it's expecting `multipart/form-data`, not `application/pdf` as I specified

### New Code

I wrote a function to convert the PDF to base64 and upload it as part of a `FormData` object.

```
convertToBase64(file) {
      if (file.length > 0) {
        let fileToLoad = file[0];
        let fileReader = new FileReader();
        let base64;
        fileReader.onload = (fileLoadedEvent) => {
          console.log('fileLoadedEvent', fileLoadedEvent);
          base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
          console.log('base64', base64);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
      } else {
        console.log('file length was 0');
      }
    },

...

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pdfFile', this.convertToBase64(this.file));

// upload code from above...
```

Still no love! Not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible.

Comment: What does the response body say, when you get the 412 error?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot see edit!

Comment: `PUT` requests expect only the object body as payload, and the `Content-Type` set to the payload MIME type.  `POST` requests expect a `multipart/form-data` web form, with the object's `Content-Type` specified as one of the form fields.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so being as using `PUT` doesn't seem to be working, I can maybe attach the PDF file to a `FormData` object somehow?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, but have resolved it.

Here's how.

First, here's the setup that always worked:

I have a nextjs app that is combination of the backend API and an index page with test buttons/functions to manually test the API.

1. The client side calls the API to get a signed URL to upload a pdf directly from the browser.
2. The API calls `createSignedPost` and sends the signature to the client.
3. The client uses `formData` to combine the signature and browser-selected file, then use the built-in `fetch()` to `POST` the file to AWS.

I decided to write a node-based cli that would simulate the browser and run all the tests.

For the cli I use [node-fetch-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-cookies) to track cookies, to simulate logging in and sending logged-in requests to the API.

**Note:** `node-fetch-cookies` uses `node-fetch` for it's async http(s) calls.

With `node-fetch-cookies` I tried using `formData` and passing in the full path to the file (failed), and using `fs.createReadStream()` as the file (also failed).

What worked:

I had to swap out the `node-fetch-cookies` `fetch()` call and use the built-in node `fetch()` call.

Here's pseudo code that demonstrates what works:

```js
const api = new API();
const file = fs.createReadStream("/path/to/file");

api
  .getSignedUrl()
  .then(async (signature) => {
    const { url, fields } = signature;
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.entries({ ...fields, file }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      formData.append(key, value);
    });
    // built-in node fetch()
    return fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
  })
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Upload failed ${response.statusText}`);
    }
    console.log("file uploaded");
  });
```

**Bonus:**

If you need to do this in the browser, you just need to swap out the `file` to use the user-selected file.

Here's how.

Instead of:

```
const file = fs.createReadStream("/path/to/file");
```

have a form element like this:

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" onChange={(e) => documentGetLocalFile(e)} />
```

and a handler like this:

```
var file;
documentGetLocalFile(event) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    file = event.target.files[0];
  }
}
```

Then just make sure your `formData` uses this `file` in place of the `fs.createReadStream()` file you removed above.